# A version of "The butterfly that Stamped" illustrated with a picture of the Taj Mahal

Tags: story-identification, illustrated-story

If I remember correctly, my family had a copy of Rudyard Kipling's *Just So Stories* (1902) that was probably published before 1960.

As I remember, in one of the stories, which I deduce should be "The Butterfly that Stamped", there is an illustration of the building with King Solomon's many wives being transported to a distant location, and that building looks a lot like the Taj Mahal.

Does anyone remember seeing that version of the story and know what edition of *Just So Stories* had that illustration?

Comment: Recognize any of these covers? http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?998508

Answer (score 2):

This sounds, *O Best Beloved*, like an edition with Kipling's original illustrations.  As well as other black-and white pictures, there was always a full-page illustration after the end of each story, with an explanatory caption.  The last one in the book shows something close to what you describe.

[image: The Butterfly Who Stamped]

> This is the picture of the four gull-winged Djinns lifting up Suleiman-bin-Daoud's Palace the very minute after the Butterfly had stamped. The Palace and the gardens and everything came up in one piece like a board, and they left a big hole in the ground all full of dust and smoke. If you look in the corner, close to the thing that looks like a lion, you will see Suleiman-bin-Daoud with his magic stick and the two Butterflies behind him. The thing that looks like a lion is really a lion carved in stone, and the thing that looks like a milk-can is really a piece of a temple or a house or something. Suleiman-bin-Daoud stood there so as to be out of the way of the dust and the smoke when the Djinns lifted up the Palace. I don't know the Djinns' names. They were servants of Suleiman-bin-Daoud's magic ring, and they changed about every day. They were just common gull-winged Djinns.
>
> The thing at the bottom is a picture of a very friendly Djinn called Akraig. He used to feed the little fishes in the sea three times a day, and his wings were made of pure copper. I put him in to show you what a nice Djinn is like. He did not help to lift the Palace. He was busy feeding little fishes in the Arabian Sea when it happened.

There are many editions that include all of the author's original illustrations (sometimes "improved" by later modifications, however).  I had two editions of the book as a child, one with completely new illustrations and another one (still in my possession) that was a facsimile of the first printing.

[image: Just So Stories]

Comment: This might be the right answer.  But I think that I remember a large paged, thin book with a shiny plastic coated hard cover, an at that the illustration I asked about was in color and had a rather accurate depiction of the Taj Mahal.  So was there such an edition or has myimaginate created unreal memory details?

Comment: @M.A.Golding It's hard to know.  *Just So Stories* is like *Alice in Wonderland*, in that it is a public domain classic that has an original "canonical" set of illustrations, but that has also been republished with new illustrations multiple time.  In my household growing up, we had two versions illustrated in very different styles—Kipling's black-and-white original, and another in color.  Yet despite the major differences, for some of the illustrations I remember, I couldn't tell you which book they came from without actually looking at a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the image that you recall?  It's the colour plate by Joseph Michael Gleeson added to the [1912 edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?333073), which you can view at the [Hathi Trust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015010350141&view=1up&seq=260).

[image: story image from The "Butterfly that Stamped" by Joseph Michael Gleeson]

The story (viewable at the link) also included 2 black-and-white images by Kipling, but neither seems closer to what you're looking for than this.  The previous (1902) editions included only the black-and-white images by Kipling.

According to ISFDb at least, the next edition was 1965 by Schocken books, but I haven't found any information about the illustrations included in this edition.

Comment: How about the black and white illo on page 241? It seems to really be a close match for "an illustration of the building with King Solomon's many wives being transported to a distant location, and that building looks a lot like the Taj Mahal."  Since it literally is a picture of the djinns picking up the palace, with a large domed building in the middle.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Egg on my face if that's true.  I'll have to take another look at it; it seemed somewhat incomprehensible when I glanced at it, but I didn't try looking at it on a decent screen.

Comment: Uploaded to here, feel free to use https://i.imgur.com/KWxAutT.jpg